How do I use groovy/scriptrunner to copy comments made on a Story to it's parent epic?
I was using Jira automate to copy comments from stories to epics and comments from sub-tasks to their parent stories. The problem is, I have to choose an actor and it's not dynamic.
Following the suggestions on this post -
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Copy-Comments-from-all-Sub-Tasks-into-the-Parent/qaq-p/1064030#U2729925
I was able to remove my sub-task to parent story automation. However, there is no "issue.isStory" to do a similar listener for story to epic.
Does anyone know of a way to use scriptrunner to copy comments made on a story to it's parent epic?
Thanks!
I've tried googling and modifying the sub-task to story script and have been unsuccessful.

Olly here from The Adaptavist Group Support!
That Script you're looking at is for a Listener - we can see this as there's mention of the event binding variable within the Script.
Using A4J, we can use the Issue Commented Rule to then Execute a ScriptRunner Script which will:

Check if the current Issue is a Story
Check if it has a Parent (an Epic in this case)
Retrieve the new Comment's Author using renderSmartValues API for Smart Values
Run as the new Author using HAPI
Add the same comment to the Parent using HAPI

For example, this could look like:
if(issue.issueType.name == 'Story'){
    def parentLinkValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue('Epic Link')
    if(parentLinkValue){
        def commentAuthor = Users.getByName(ruleContext.renderSmartValues('{{issue.comments.last.author.name}}'))
        Users.runAs(commentAuthor){
            Issues.getByKey(parentLinkValue.key).addComment(ruleContext.renderSmartValues('{{issue.comments.last.body}}'))
        }
    }
}

Hope this helps! :)

Once I figured out to put that in the automation, it worked perfectly, thanks!
